# Изменение данных бд пользователем через форму на сайте

Tags: python, django, postgresql

У меня есть выведенная на сайте таблица (атрибуты: `id_store` (основной ключ), `id_dr`, `id_ph` (это ключи из других таблиц), `price`, `amount` (просто числа)), которая есть в базе данных (есть соответствующий view для вывода). Также есть форма, чтобы заполнить её данными строки из таблицы.

`views.py`:

```py
def table(request):
    op = Store.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'data/table.html', {'op': op})
```

`table.html`:

```html
{% block content %}
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Drugs</th>
      <th>Pharmacy</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {% for store in op %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ store.id_store }}</td>
      <td>{{ store.id_dr }}</td>
      <td>{{ store.id_ph }}</td>
      <td>{{ store.price }}</td>
      <td>{{ store.amount }}</td>
    </tr>
        {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>

<form class="table" method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="number" name="id_store" value="{{ store.id_store }}">
  <input type="number" name="id_dr" value="{{ store.id_dr }}">
  <input type="number" name="id_ph" value="{{ store.id_ph }}">
  <input type="number" name="price" value="{{ store.price }}">
  <input type="number" name="amount" value="{{ store.amount }}">
  <button type="submit">Edit</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Я написал вот такое view, чтобы после ввода в форму данных по айди менялась соответствующая строка в бд, что и на сайте должно быть сразу видно.

```py
def store_edit(request, store_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        store = get_object_or_404(Store, id_store=store_id)
        store.id_store = request.POST.get('id_store')
        store.id_dr = request.POST.get('id_dr')
        store.id_ph = request.POST.get('id_ph')
        store.price = request.POST.get('price')
        store.amount = request.POST.get('amount')
        store.save()
        return JsonResponse({'status': 'success'})
```

Но при заполнении формы и нажатии кнопки ничего не сохраняется. Подскажите, в чем ошибка (urls есть). В идеале вообще должно быть реализовано без ввода `id_store` в форму. Просто должна выбираться строка в таблице нажатием, а форма становится активной, после чего вводятся данные и нажимается submit. Это уже через javascript должно быть, наверное. Но мне бы понять, почему не работает то, что есть.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form class="table" method="POST" action ="{% url 'адрес вашей функции store_edit'  store.id %}"
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="number" name="id_store" value="{{ store.id_store }}">
    <input type="number" name="id_dr" value="{{ store.id_dr }}">
    <input type="number" name="id_ph" value="{{ store.id_ph }}">
    <input type="number" name="price" value="{{ store.price }}">
    <input type="number" name="amount" value="{{ store.amount }}">
    <button type="submit">Edit</button>
</form>
```

Проблема вашего подхода в том что в queryset op много объектов store. И в форму будет передано только одно значение store.id, при этом в вашем шаблоне не реализован функционал выбора какому именно объекту store необходимо внести изменения.

Comment: Можно подробнее?

Comment: Вам необходимо в функцию store_edit передать id записи которую вы хотите редактировать. В этом месте action ="{% url 'адрес вашей функции store_edit'  store.id %}" ----- store.id (id объекта store который нужно редактировать). При этом вы в шаблоне не отразили каким образом вы выберите конкретную запись (конкретную строку в таблице).